# Screenshots at Beginning and End of Video

Tags: bash, unix, video, ffmpeg

I have over 1700 emulator videos I need to take screenshots of. I need one set of (Action) screenshots about 5 seconds into the start of the video and another set of (Title) screenshots at about 2 seconds from the end of video.

For the Action Shots (Start) I've got:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 5 -i "VideoName.mp4" -vframes 1 "Action/VideoName.png"
```

And for Title Shots (End) I've got:

```
ffmpeg -sseof -2 -i "VideoName.mp4" -vframes 1 "Title/VideoName.png"
```

But now I need these new image's to retain the same filename as the source.

For example:

```
Donkey Kong.mp4 > Action/Donkey Kong.png
```

And I also need to be able to do this to many video files.

Any help will be much appreciated, Nem

Answer (score 1):

To take a screenshot from 2.5 seconds before the end of the video, use

```
ffmpeg -sseof -2.5 -i input.mp4 -vframes 1 input-end.png
```

Answer (score 1):

The following did the trick for Action shots:

```
mkdir Action

for i in *.mp4
do
 ffmpeg -y -ss 5 -i "$i" -vframes 1 "Action/$i.png"
done
```

For some reason the .mp4 extension remained in the image name.
For example:

```
Donkey Kong.mp4.png
```

So I used the following to fix that:

```
cd Action

rename 's/.mp4//g' *.png

cd ..
```

To get:

```
Donkey Kong.png
```

Comment: Use bash parameter expansion to prevent the `.mp4` in the output file name: `"Action/${i%.*}.png"`